# Grunt html livereload

Tags: html, gruntjs

I'm using a super simple grunt file that watches and complies my sass files and then livereloads the page using the chrome extension.

This is all working fine but I also wanted to watch for changes in the html file and liverload when I make changes and save.

Can any tell me why this doesn't work

```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

      // Sass processing

      sass: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            "css/styles.css": "css/scss/styles.scss"
          }
        }
      },

      // Growl notifications
      notify: {
        full: {
          options: {
            message: 'Project compiled'
          }
        },
        sass: {
          options: {
            message: 'Sass compiled'
          }
        },
        html: {
          options: {
            message: 'html updated'
          }
        }
      },

      // File Watcher
      watch: {
        sass: {
          files: ['css/scss/*.scss'],
          tasks: ['sass', 'notify:sass'],
          options:{
            livereload: true
          }
        },

        html: {
          files: ['index.html','**/*.html','**/*.css'],
          tasks: ['notify:html'],
          options:{
            livereload: true
          }
        }
      }

    });


    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

  };
```

Comment: Do you receive the html notification? (the notify task)

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. the html watch needs to come before the sass watch